# Eclipse plugin: How to find from which View the user opened a Dialog?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I know how to find out whether a View like the "Project Explorer" is open in Eclipse. But how can I determine if the user opened a dialog from the "z/OS Projects" View or from the "Project Explorer" View?

On base of the result, I need to locate a file in the current active View.
This part I got covered already.

Comment: I don't think you can. It is normal to use use the current selection rather than trying to find a view. This is straightforward in a handler.

Comment: Thanks Greg, can you follow up on this by giving an example? :-)

Comment: Not until you give more information. Is this a dialog you are opening from and command handler (something extending AbstractHandler)? If not what are you doing?

Comment: Sure.
I am opening a LocateMemberHandler:

public class LocateMemberHandler extends AbstractHandler{

It is used to quickly locate files accross the workbench. A Locate button on the dialog will locate the selected file in z/OS Projects or Project Explorer (expanding all folders) without opening the source code.

Answer (score 0):

In a handler class extending `AbstractHandler` you can use the `HandlerUtil` method to get various information from the execution event.

For the current selection you can use:

```
IStructuredSelection sel = HandlerUtil.getCurrentStructuredSelection(event);
```

where `event` is the `ExecutionEvent` passed to the handler.

To get any resource (such as an `IFile`) contained in the selection use:

```
IResource resource = Adapters.adapt(sel.getFirstElement(), IResource.class);
```

(you may also be able to adapt directly to `IFile`).

Note: both `getCurrentStructuredSelection` and `Adapters` are only in fairly recent versions of Eclipse. For older versions the code is a little more complex.